# General Proof that $\left< v, v \right> = \left|\left| v \right|\right|^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Consider $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the standard Euclidean inner-product. I'm trying to give a proof that

$$
\left< v, v \right> = \left|\left| v \right|\right|^2
$$

but can only seem to do it for $\mathbb{R}^2$ where you can use the geometric definition of the dot product, namely

$$
u \cdot v = \left|\left|u\right|\right|\left|\left|v\right|\right|\cos(\theta).
$$

Any idea how to generalize the proof for $n > 2$?

Comment: $\langle v,v\rangle = \sum_k v_k v_k = \sum v_k^2 = \|v\|^2$?

Comment: Uh...it depends on your definition. This could be something true by definition, or true after a tiny bit of algebra, or true after a bit of geometry. What's your definition of $\langle v,v\rangle$ and $||v||$?

Comment: He did write 'standard Euclidean inner-product'...

Comment: The problem with the "geometric definition of the dot product" is, where does the $θ$ come from? Or at least the $\cos(θ)$? If you do not want to invoke the sum of coordinate product formula, because you are just proving it, it seems hard to give a non-circular analytical definition.

Comment: @copper.hat: what standard? There are at least 3 definition all define the same standard, ie. all are equivalence. Which is why whether this proof is trivial or slightly less trivial depend on which definition.

Comment: @Gina: I only know of one standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Just as there is one standard orthonormal basis.

Comment: @copper.hat: there is only 1 standard (ie. there is only 1 standard function that assign a real value to a pair of vectors), and there are many different equivalent definition, all defining the same function. So yes, you only know 1 standard, but do you know the different definition? I suspected that the asker do not even understand how is $||v||$ even defined, which is why I pushed. Because seriously, on the inner product definition this question is so trivial that it literally can be proved by saying "that's the definition".

Answer (score 1):

If your definition is the inner product space definition, that is $||v||$ is defined as $\sqrt{\langle v,v\rangle}$, then the problem is instantly trivial.

If your definition is the coordinate definition, that is $||v||$ is defined as $\sqrt{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}v_{i}^{2}}$, and $\langle u,v\rangle$ is defined as $\sqrt{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}u_{i}v_{i}}$, then the problem is instantly trivial.

If your definition is the geometric definition, that is you first impose an Euclidean plane that contains all the involved vector and then use the angle, then your proof reduced to the $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ case.

Answer (score 1):

The only sensible interpretation would be in the sense of the polarization formulas. That is, the formula for the norm is given and one exploits it to find related quantities.

The most basic geometric construction that is related to the norm is the projection of a point onto a line. Given points $A$ and $B$ and a direction $v$, find the point closest to $B$ on the line $A+tv$. Using the definition of the euclidean norm, this leads to a quadratic equation in $t$ where the square can be again completed,

\begin{align}
\|A+tv-B\|^2
& =\|tv-AB\|^2=\sum_i\left[t^2v_i^2-2tv_i(AB)_i+(AB)_i^2\right]\\
& = t^2\|v\|^2-2t\sum_iv_i(AB)_i+\|AB\|^2\\
& = \left(t\|v\|-\frac{\sum_iv_i(AB)_i}{\|v\|}\right)^2+\|AB\|^2-\left(\frac{\sum_iv_i(AB)_i}{\|v\|}\right)^2
\end{align}

So the remaining  sum inside the last line seems to be an important quantity, give it the symbol $v\cdot AB$ or $\langle v,\,AB\rangle$ and explore further uses. Turns out it is rather ubiquitous.